# Formato de fecha phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Quisiera saber si se puede cambiar el formato de fecha en el phpmyadmin.

Necesito que solo aparezcan lo que es el mes y el dia.

Estoy usando el datepicker de jquery, porque me pidieron que cuando el cliente registre su fecha de cumpleaños solo ponga el mes y el dia, ya logre quitar el año del calendario.

Pero cuando hago el insert en la base de datos se insertan 0000-00-00, entonces quiero saber si se puede que el phpmyadmin acepte solo el formato de mes y dia o que acepte el mes y el dia y el año lo deje en 0.

Gracias

Comment: que has intentado?, checa [ask]

Comment: @BetaM Ya actualice mi pregunte gracias !!

Comment: Lo mejor seria que compartieras aquello que hayas intentado, por otro lado ¿no sería más factible guardar la fecha de nacimiento?, así obtienes el cumpleaños y la edad (si en algún momento te la solicitan). Saludos.

Comment: Excelente observación y propuesta @Josue, por qué si en algún momento requieres la fecha de nacimiento completa para otros cálculos como le harías?

Comment: Hola a todos! muchas gracias por sus comentarios. Esto mas que nada es por cuestion de pensamientos lo de quitar el año, porque varios clientes no ingresan su fecha de nacimiento(Por lo mismo de no querer dar su edad) Pero muchas gracias, usare lo mas conveniente

Comment: 1/2 Siempre conviene guardar fechas completas, incluyendo el año, de lo contrario tu columna en la BD no podrá ser del tipo `Date` o `DateTime` y eso te traerá muchas complicaciones al momento de mostrar los datos formateados o al momento de hacer cálculos, etc. Además estarás desperdiciando espacio al usar dos columnas para guardar datos cuando podrías usar sólo una...

Comment: 2/2 ... En cuanto a aquellos usuarios que no quieren que se sepa la edad, podrías optar por una política que consistiría en ¡hacer que sean ellos los más viejos! :) No es broma, para ellos asignas un año por defecto, por ejemplo, puede asignarles como año de nacimiento el `1900`. Así solventas la dificultad de guardar diferenciado un dato que debería estar unido.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor manera de guardar información referida a la fecha, incluso si el año no es requerido, es usar el tipo date. Lo único que tenés que hacer es ignorarlo dentro de tu código.

Usar Date facilita el ordenado, la integridad, la validación, etc.

Si aún así querés guardarlo de otra manera, podrías utilizar dos columnas tinyint.

```
CREATE TABLE `nombre-tabla` (
  `dia` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `mes` tinyint NOT NULL
);
```

Espero haberte ayudado!